# How to add VKontakte, Mail.ru and Yandex as identity providers to Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I need our two local Identity Providers - VK, Mail.ru and Yandex - to my Azure AD B2C. Is this possible? Any hints?

Comment: You can achieve this using advanced policies of B2C. But before that make sure both the providers support integration with 3rd parties. Check the article @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-goog-idp for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they support OpenID Connect, you can now do this with built-in policies: [Add a custom OpenID Connect identity provider in built-in policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-oidc-idp)